# Can I bypass the 10 min limit?

Tags: symphony

In Symphony, the player can choose music from his library to play, much like Audiosurf. But the game refuses to play any songs longer than 10 minutes. Sadly, some of my favorite songs are longer than this.

Is there any way to bypass this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they have [commented](http://www.moddb.com/games/symphony/page/2#comments) on it before, saying that it is there to avoid memory issues.

They said they may add the ability with an update, but have not yet done so (as of 8/6/2012).